# Python match similar strings and group them together from two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, algorithm

I have two lists in python:

```
A = ["Opn", "Jan-20 A", "Feb-20 A", "Mar-20 A"]
B = ["Jan-20 B", "Mar-20 B", "Apr-20 B", "Cls"]
```

I want to group together strings that have a similar month-year and get the output as follows. The strings that do not have a match get grouped with empty strings

```
[("Opn",""),("Jan-20 A","Jan-20 B"),("Feb-20 A",""),("Mar-20 A","Mar-20 B"),("","Apr-20 B"),("","Cls")]
```

My approach is this. It is O(n^2), was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do so.

```
output = []
pair = False
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        if i.split()[0] == j.split()[0]:
            output.append((i,j))
            pair = True
            B.remove(j)
            break
    if not(pair):
        output.append((i,''))
    pair = False
output = output + [("",j) for j in B]
```

What would be an efficient way to do so?

Comment: Please, share what you have tried and what is your issue with it.

Comment: Are the strings random? `Opn` and `Cls` - what are these?

Comment: Yes there can be random strings. Only need to group the strings that match. Give me 2 min, I will post my approach. Its O(n^2), was wondering if there is a more efficient approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. This is a O(n) solution

```
A = ["Opn", "Jan-20 A", "Feb-20 A", "Mar-20 A"]
B = ["Jan-20 B", "Mar-20 B", "Apr-20 B", "Cls"]

store ={}
output = []

for i in A:
    store[i.split()[0]] =i;

# print(store)

for j in B:
    key = j.split()[0]
    if key in store:
        output.append((store[key],j))
        del store[key]
    else:
        output.append(('',j))

for key in store:
    output.append((store[key],''))

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, if performance is not an issue:

```
A = ["Opn", "Jan-20 A", "Feb-20 A", "Mar-20 A"]
B = ["Jan-20 B", "Mar-20 B", "Apr-20 B", "Cls"]

res=[(i, '') for i in A]

for i in range(len(res)):
    for k in B:
        if res[i][0][:6]==k[:6]:
            res[i]=(res[i][0], k)

for k in B:
    if all(i[:6]!=k[:6] for i in A):
        res.append(('',k)) 

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[('Opn', ''), ('Jan-20 A', 'Jan-20 B'), ('Feb-20 A', ''), ('Mar-20 A', 'Mar-20 B'), ('', 'Apr-20 B'), ('', 'Cls')]
```

Comment: The approach I have posted above (in the question) has the same time complexity of O(n^2). I am looking for a more efficient way to do this

Comment: Are all of your strings of the same format? ('XXX-XX A' or 'XXX-XX B')? If not is the common substring of equal length for all pairs (6)? Any info would help

Comment: Some of the strings that are supposed to match will always be in the same format (MMM-YY A or MMM-YY B). Others not in this format would not match and that is ok

Answer (score -1):

Using `dict` you can get O(n+m)

```py
from collections import defaultdict 
from itertools import chain

d = defaultdict(list)

A = ["Opn", "Jan-20 A", "Feb-20 A", "Mar-20 A"]
B = ["Jan-20 B", "Mar-20 B", "Apr-20 B", "Cls"]

for i in chain(A,B):
    d[i[:6]].append(i)

print(list(d.values()))
```

````
[['Opn'], ['Jan-20 A', 'Jan-20 B'], ['Feb-20 A'], ['Mar-20 A', 'Mar-20 B'], ['Apr-20 B'], ['Cls']]
​```
````